# How to formulate a constraint to order the items in ascending order in PuLP?

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, pulp

I am using the PuLP package to solve a bin-packing problem and I wanted to formulate a constraint to group the items based on days in ascending order.

Below is the code snippet that is giving us the results which are not desired.

```
from itertools import product
import pandas as pd
import pulp

df = pd.DataFrame([["item0", 9, 6],["item1", 9, 8],["item2", 9, 1],
    ["item3", 1, 7],["item4", 1, 3],["item5", 9, 5]], columns=["itemname", "Quantity", "Days"])

df = df.sort_values('Days').reset_index(drop = True)
max_weight = 20
max_bins = 4
bin_penalty = 5
day_penalty = 10
bins = list(range(max_bins))

problem = pulp.LpProblem("sort_item_ascending", pulp.LpMinimize)

bin_used = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("is_bin_used", bins, cat="Binary")

# Possible combinations to put the item in the bin
possible_item_in_bin = [(item_index, bin_num) for item_index, bin_num in product(df.index, bins)]

item_in_bin = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("is_item_in_bin", possible_item_in_bin, cat="Binary")

# Formula to ensure each item is loaded only in one bin
for item_index in df.index:
    problem += (pulp.lpSum([item_in_bin[item_index, bin_index] for bin_index in bins]) == 1,
        f"Ensure that item {item_index} is only in one bin")

# Sum of quantity grouped in each bin must be less than max weight
for bin_index in bins:
    problem += (pulp.lpSum(
            [ item_in_bin[item_index, bin_index] * df.loc[item_index, "Quantity"] for item_index in df.index ]
        ) <= max_weight * bin_used[bin_index],
        f"Sum of wieghts in bin {bin_index} should not exceed max weight {max_weight}")

# CORE LOGIC: To calculate the sum of days in each bin
days_diff = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("days_diff", bins, cat = 'Integer')
for b in bins:
    problem += pulp.lpSum([item_in_bin[item_index, b] * df.loc[item_index, "Days"] for item_index in df.index]) - days_diff[b] == 0

problem += (
    (day_penalty * pulp.lpSum(days_diff[b] for b in bins)) + (bin_penalty * pulp.lpSum(bin_used[b] for b in bins)), "Objective: Minimize Bins Used and sum of days")

problem.solve(pulp.PULP_CBC_CMD(msg=True))

# Assign the bin numbers to the items
for idx, b in possible_item_in_bin:
    if item_in_bin[idx, b].varValue == 1:
        df.loc[idx, 'bin'] = b
```

**Current output**

[image: Current Output]

**Desired output**

[image: Desired Output]

The current formulation for days is working as expected and need help to formulate it to group the items in ascending order.

**NOTE:** Since the max weight of each bin is 20. we are not able to accommodate item0 of days 6 in bin2.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated & Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by cleverly using the `bin number`/`days` as a penalty in your objective function.  (See the modified objective below.)

This will incentivize putting low-day items in low number bins.

Realize, you may discover corner cases that might use an extra bin because of this penalty, so you might need to tinker with the weights of the 2 parts of the objective and check some corner cases...

##### Code:

```
from itertools import product
import pandas as pd
import pulp

df = pd.DataFrame([["item0", 9, 6],["item1", 9, 8],["item2", 9, 1],
    ["item3", 1, 7],["item4", 1, 3],["item5", 9, 5]], columns=["itemname", "Quantity", "Days"])

df = df.sort_values('Days').reset_index(drop = True)
max_weight = 20
max_bins = 4
bin_penalty = 5
day_penalty = 10
bins = list(range(max_bins))

problem = pulp.LpProblem("sort_item_ascending", pulp.LpMinimize)

bin_used = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("is_bin_used", bins, cat="Binary")

# Possible combinations to put the item in the bin
possible_item_in_bin = [(item_index, bin_num) for item_index, bin_num in product(df.index, bins)]

item_in_bin = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("is_item_in_bin", possible_item_in_bin, cat="Binary")

# Formula to ensure each item is loaded only in one bin
for item_index in df.index:
    problem += (pulp.lpSum([item_in_bin[item_index, bin_index] for bin_index in bins]) == 1,
        f"Ensure that item {item_index} is only in one bin")

# Sum of quantity grouped in each bin must be less than max weight
for bin_index in bins:
    problem += (pulp.lpSum(
            [ item_in_bin[item_index, bin_index] * df.loc[item_index, "Quantity"] for item_index in df.index ]
        ) <= max_weight * bin_used[bin_index],
        f"Sum of wieghts in bin {bin_index} should not exceed max weight {max_weight}")

# CORE LOGIC: To calculate the sum of days in each bin
# days_diff = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("days_diff", bins, cat = 'Integer')
# for b in bins:
#     problem += pulp.lpSum([item_in_bin[item_index, b] * df.loc[item_index, "Days"] for item_index in df.index]) - days_diff[b] == 0

problem += (
    (pulp.lpSum(b / df.loc[i, "Days"] * item_in_bin[i, b]  for i in df.index for b in bins)) +
    (bin_penalty * pulp.lpSum(bin_used[b] for b in bins)), "Objective: Minimize Bins Used and sum of days")

problem.solve(pulp.PULP_CBC_CMD(msg=True))

# Assign the bin numbers to the items
for idx, b in possible_item_in_bin:
    if item_in_bin[idx, b].varValue == 1:
        df.loc[idx, 'bin'] = b

print(df)
```

##### Output:

```
  itemname  Quantity  Days  bin
0    item2         9     1  0.0
1    item4         1     3  0.0
2    item5         9     5  0.0
3    item0         9     6  1.0
4    item3         1     7  0.0
5    item1         9     8  1.0
```

Comment: I have a couple of questions about this

1.You've mentioned adding days/binnumber as a penalty to the objective function but seems like in code it is written as bin number/days. Could you confirm the code one is correct?
2. Can I add it as a constraint instead of directly adding it to the objective function? I'm asking this so that I can prioritize/de-prioritize it in future with the help of penalty values.

Comment: well, the code one speaks for itself in the result, no?  I fixed typo in post.  I can't see a way to put that into a constraint.  What would you constrain it to?  I would just put a scalar "weight" value in front of it and then tinker with the weights, or zero out the weight if you want to ignore that portion of the objective fn.